# scala forward reference extends over definition

Tags: scala

```
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

sealed trait Stream[+A] {

  def toList: List[A] = {
    val buf = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]
    def go(s: Stream[A]): List[A] = s match {
      case Cons(h, t) =>
        buf += h()
        go(t())
      case _ => buf.toList
    }
    go(this)
  }

  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = Stream.cons(hd, tl)

  def empty = Stream.empty

  def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A] = f(z) match {
    case Some((h,t)) => cons(h, unfold(t)(f))
    case None => empty
  }

  def take(n: Int): Stream[A] = unfold((this, n)) {
    case (Cons(h, t), 1) => Some((h(), (empty, 0)))
    case (Cons(h, t), n) if n > 1 => Some((h(), (t(), n-1)))
    case (Empty, 0) => None
  }
}

object Stream {

  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = Cons(() => hd, () => tl)

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)
}

object StreamTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //why compile error: forward reference extends over definition of value ones
    /*val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)
    println(ones.take(5).toList)*/

    println(Stream.ones.take(5).toList)
  }
}
```

***why compile error?: forward reference extends over definition of value ones***

in pair object 'Stream', 
***val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.scons(1, ones)*** is ok

but in main method, it's not ok (but... same synthetics!)

Comment: @m-z please delete comment sign(/* */) in main method, `/*val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)
    println(ones.take(5).toList)*/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local vals are not members.

For your test code, do this:

```
object StreamTest extends App {
  //def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //why compile error: forward reference extends over definition of value ones
    val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)
    println(ones.take(5).toList)

    println(Stream.ones.take(5).toList)
  //}
}
```

The restriction in blocks is worded [in the spec here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html), where the other advice is to make it a lazy val in the block, which has the same effect.

Comment: it works! without main method, StreamTest object runs... maybe the reason is `extends App` I think. `lazy val` approach is also works well. restriction in block is quite interesting. thanks!

Comment: `App` lets the initializer run from `main` but you keep template semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The forward reference is in `Cons[+A]...`which is referenced in this line:

```
def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = Cons(() => hd, () => tl)
```

Try to move

```
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

into the companion object.

Comment: move `Empty, Cons` into `object Stream` and change `Cons => Stream.Cons and Empty => Stream.Empty` to get off compile errors. But nothing changes